# Can we send normal text messages from WiFi with cellular iPad?

Tags: objective-c

I am developing app for iPad and i want to send text message(not iMessage) from my app. Is it possible through iPad which has WiFi with Cellular?

Comment: Try to elaborate your question a bit more. It's hard to understand what do you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, since the iPad does not have any support for SMS. Even Apples own Messages.app does not support SMS on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup an external server that handles sending the actual texts. As for making the app send texts using the iPad's GSM signal it is impossible